# Converting Dates Freemarker

Tags: freemarker, date-formatting

I'm trying to get the following to work but I can't get the correct value to display.

Assuming SHIPPING_DATE is treated as a string with the value = 2016/05/23:

```
<#setting date_format="MM/dd/yyyy">
<#setting locale="en_US">

<#assign ship_date>${SHIPPING_DATE}</#assign>

${ship_date?date("MM/dd/yyyy")}
```

The output is **12/05/0190** but I'm expecting **05/23/2016**. Will someone help but also explain what I'm doing wrong, please?

Comment: Minor correction: * <#assign ship_date>${SHIPPING_DATE}</#assign>

Comment: Or rather just `<#assign ship_date = SHIPPING_DATE>`, as `SHIPPING_DATE` is already a string. Which in turn makes the whole assignment unnecessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a *string* in `ship_date` like `2016/05/23`, then you can parse it to a real date value with `ship_date?date("yyyy/MM/dd")`. Note that it's not `MM/dd/yyyy`, as in your example. `?date` means "convert to date", and you specify to it how to interpret the string. Then, when you print a real date value (not a string) with `${...}`, then it will be converted to string according the `data_format` configuration setting, so then `MM/dd/yyyy` will be good. It doesn't mater how that real date value was get (like with `string?date(format)` or directly from the data-model).

Comment: This worked! Thank you for your help and explanation. I was misinterpreting the ?date function. I didn't realize that was stating "this is a date", I thought I needed something extra to convert. This was very helpful.

Comment: Usually, nouns and adjectives after `?` mean "to <something>". Like `?upper_case` means "to upper case", `?string` means "to string". And, you are supposed to accept the answer (add that check mark to it).

Answer (score 0):

*template.ftl*

```
<#list listaCategoria as c>
   <tr>
      <td> ${c.dataCadastro?datetime("yyyy-MM-dd")?string("dd/MM/yyyy")}</td>
   </tr>
</#list>
```

*RelatorioService.java*

```
LocalDate dataCadastro = LocalDate.of(1995, 12, 7);
```

Result:

```
07/12/1995
```