# Freemarker - Converting 01-JAN -1960 to 01/01/1960

Tags: date, freemarker

I am using free marker and I new to it. I have a text field that lists a date as 01-JAN-1960. I need it to read as 01/01/1960. These dates are just place holders, there are various dates that will need to be converted like this. Any suggestions?

Comment: you should tell us what you have tried already. Have you done a search in the manual for instance? [Frmarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_custom_formats.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert date in specific format in Freemarker template or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857058/how-to-convert-date-in-specific-format-in-freemarker-template-or-javascript)

Comment: ... or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235637/converting-dates-freemarker

Comment: Also, know if you indeed want to "convert", rather than just format a Java `Date` object. The need for converting between string representations of a date is almost always a sign of a mistake outside the template.